# Get predictions probability of 1 rather than [0;1] using Logistic Regression model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression

I fitted a `LogisticRegression` on a training set and a test set and got accuracies of ~80%

Then i wanted to make predictions on the test set, giving scores of each `student_id` depending on whether they `answered_correctly` or not [1 if yes, 0 if no].

I did this :

```
features_X = X.columns # getting columns names of X 

# X_test is an array created from a previous train_test_split step.
test_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=features_X, data=X_test)

predictions = grid_logit.predict(test_df[features_X])
#Create a  DataFrame with predictions
submission = pd.DataFrame({'Id':test_df['student_id'],'Answered_correctly':predictions})

#Visualize the first 5 rows
submission.head()

Id           Answered_correctly
12992348        0
7268428         0
9497321         1 
588792          1
5045118         1
```

As you can see it classifies each user between 0  and 1.

What i want is something like this :

```
Id            Answered_correctly
12992348            0.32
7268428             0.52
9497321             0.65
```

`answered_correctly_`values corresponding to the probability of being class 1.

NB: Using `predict_proba`function returns an error :

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

**EDIT** :
I replaced `predict` with `predict_proba(test_df[[features_X]])` 
but it returns an error : `None of [[ features_X cols]] are in the [columns]`

Comment: `predict_proba` gives you what you're looking for. You didn't show the code where you try to call it

Comment: @krisograbek I didn't show it because i just replaced it in the above code.  `grid_logit.predict_proba `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predict_proba` returns the probability estimates for each class. Given that you have two classes (0 and 1), it will return an array of shape `(n_samples, 2)`.

The error message originates from the pandas dataframe, as it requires you to pass 1-dimensional data only. As mentioned above, `predictions` is but a 2-dimensional output.

Only pass the probability estimates for class 1 (`predictions[:, 1]`) to the dataframe constructor and it should work fine:

```py
submission = pd.DataFrame({'Id': test_df['student_id'], 'Answered_correctly': predictions[:, 1]})
```

---

Additional note:

If `test_df` has all columns given by `features_X`, you do not need to pass `test_df[features_X]` since `test_df` should be sufficient:

```py
predictions = grid_logit.predict_proba(test_df)
```